# Optional keyword argument and multiple arguments exercise

Tags: scheme, racket

I have to write a function pow-increase which accepts an arbitrary number of arguments and one optional parameter. For each argument, it must calculate its power to some number, which is incremented for every argument, starting with the number 2, or, if the optional keyword argument is supplied, starts with that number.

Example:

```
> (pow-increase 2 2 2 2) ; 2^2 2^3 2^4 2^5
'(4 8 16 32)

> (pow-increase #start: 1 2 2 2 2) ; 2^1 2^2 2^3 2^4
'(2 4 8 16)
```

I've already written the function for the first call:

```
(define pow-increase
    (lambda argList 
        (let* ([len (length argList)]
               [exponents (range 2 (+ len 2) 1)])
        (map (lambda (x) (expt (car x) (car(cdr x)))) (zip argList exponents)))))
```

Now I'd like to write the second version of the function (for the second call) but I don't know how to pass simultaneously an arbitrary number of arguments and an optional keyword argument. I've read [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/lambda.html#%28part._.Declaring_.Optional_.Arguments%29) the syntax for optional arguments is: [optParamName value].

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for

```
(define (pow-increase #:start (start 2) . lst)
  (for/list ((e (in-list lst)) (i (in-naturals start)))
    (expt e i)))
```

testing

```
> (pow-increase 2 2 2 2)
'(4 8 16 32)
> (pow-increase #:start 1 2 2 2 2)
'(2 4 8 16)
```

Note how elegant the code can become if you use Racket's `for` loops. If you want to stay with your initial version, the modification would be:

```
(define pow-increase
  (lambda (#:start (start 2) . argList)
    (let* ([len (length argList)]
           [exponents (range start (+ len start) 1)])
      (map (lambda (x) (expt (car x) (car (cdr x)))) (zip argList exponents)))))
```

but even then, you can simplify by getting rid of `zip` since `map` allows for more than one list:

```
(define pow-increase
  (lambda (#:start (start 2) . argList)
    (let* ([len (length argList)]
           [exponents (range start (+ len start) 1)])
      (map expt argList exponents))))
```